# Grouppositions of the 2nd level group in a 3 Level ExpandableListView is 0

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

Hi everyone I am doing a Three level ExpandablelistView from the tutorial [here](http://harrane.blogspot.in/2013/04/three-level-expandablelistview.html#comment-form). 
List items are showing correctly but the 2nd level group's groupposition is 0 in every item.
I used this code to get group position.

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("GROUP POSITION= "+gpos);
            }
        });
```

My full Adapter code:

```
    public class Adapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
      private List<Object> objects;
      private Activity activity;
      private LayoutInflater inflater;

     public Adapter(Activity activity, List<Object> objects) {
       this.objects= objects;
       this.activity= activity;
       this.inflater= (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     }

     @Override
     public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
      return objects.get(groupPosition).getObjects().get(childPosition);
     }

     @Override
     public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
      return childPosition;
     }

     @Override
     public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
       boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

      Object object= (Object) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
      CustomExpandableListView subObjects= (CustomExpandableListView) convertView;;
      if (convertView==null) {
       subObjects= new CustomExpandableListView(activity);
      }
      Adapter2 adapter= new Adapter2(activity, object);
      subObjects.setAdapter(adapter);

      return subObjects;
     }

     @Override
     public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
      return objects.get(groupPosition).getObjects().size();
     }

     @Override
     public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
      return objects.get(groupPosition);
     }

     @Override
     public int getGroupCount() {
      return objects.size();
     }

     @Override
     public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
      return groupPosition;
     }

     @Override
     public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
       View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

      Object object= (Object) getGroup(groupPosition);
      if (convertView==null) {
       convertView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_element, null);
      }

      TextView name= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
      name.setText(object.getName());

      return convertView;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean hasStableIds() {
      return true;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
      return true;
     }
    }


    class Adapter2 extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
     private Object object;
     private LayoutInflater inflater; 
     private Activity activity;

     public Adapter2(Activity activity, Object object) {
      this.activity= activity;
      this.object= object;
      this.inflater= (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     }

     @Override
     public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
      return object.getObjects().get(childPosition);
     }

     @Override
     public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
      return childPosition;
     }

     @Override
     public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
       boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

      Object object= (Object) getChild(0, childPosition);
      if (convertView==null) {
       convertView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_element, null);

       Resources r = activity.getResources();
       float px40 = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 40, r.getDisplayMetrics());
       convertView.setPadding(
         convertView.getPaddingLeft() + (int) px40,
         convertView.getPaddingTop(),
         convertView.getPaddingRight(),
         convertView.getPaddingBottom());
      }

      TextView name= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
      name.setText(object.getName());

      return convertView;
     }

     @Override
     public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
      return object.getObjects().size();
     }

     @Override
     public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
      return object;
     }

     @Override
     public int getGroupCount() {
      return 1;
     }

     @Override
     public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
      return groupPosition;
     }

     @Override
     public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
       View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

      if (convertView==null) {
       convertView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_element, null);
       Resources r = activity.getResources();
       float px20 = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20,      r.getDisplayMetrics());
       convertView.setPadding(
         convertView.getPaddingLeft() + (int) px20,
         convertView.getPaddingTop(),
         convertView.getPaddingRight(),
         convertView.getPaddingBottom()); 
      }

      TextView name= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
      name.setText(object.getName());    
   convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("GROUP POSITION= "+gpos);
        }
    });
      return convertView;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean hasStableIds() {
      return true;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
      return true;
     }
    }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: While I can't help you, I can say that embedding an adapter inside an adapter is a horrible idea. The performance implications are terrible alone. Not to mention Android does not like embedding scrollable widgets within scrollable widgets when both scroll in the same direction. You should be rethinking your UI approach.

Comment: @JaySoyer Thanks for your reply. I used that way because it is the easiest way to do a 3 level Expandablelistview as I am using it with checkboxes in all levels. If you know any good 3 level exp listview tutorials/code please give me.

Comment: @JaySoyer Which is the best alternate way to do this???

Comment: That's very situational dependent. Post a new question if you want to get ideas for alternative ways to display your information to the user.

Comment: I have checkboxes in every level. I managed to do its all click listeners and everything. But current problem is 2nd level gets collapsed when scrolling. Its reason is Recycling of view as I am using setadapter in childView of 1st adapter. Now I am looking for a way to fix this...

Comment: @JaySoyer I asked about it here. But havent got any help.. :(  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27379273/expanded-sub-items-gets-collapsed-after-scrolling-in-three-level-expandablelistv